# Collection only with relationship fields?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to return the only fields I needed but when the collection has relationship it would not work.

For example:

```
$items = $items->map(function($item) {
    return collect($item)->only([
        'id',
        'posts.title',
        'name',
        'created_at'
    ]);
});
```

Only thing that did not return is `'posts.title'`

How to solve this?

Comment: @lewis4u This is not correct. $items is already loaded with relationship.

Comment: OK i see....the problem is that you are trying to get the value from another table. If Alexey Mezenin comes he will solve this better than me. It's a very interesting question...i would also like to know the answer.